# Не срабатывает запрос mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Доброго времени суток есть таблица mysql

```
 number             customer    price   id
    (093)566-66-66  a0191934996 100     13
    (093)566-66-66  a0191934996 100     14
```

я делаю следующий запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cart WHERE customer "a0191934996"
```

выдает ошибку      #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"a0191934996"' at line 1. auto inсrement и  primary key не подскажите в чем ошибка учитывая что поиск должен быть по полю  customer имено с данными a0191934996 и они строковые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пропустили знак "="

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM wp_cart WHERE customer = "a0191934996"
```

Comment: все получилось здорово спасибо прыгаю до потолка